# Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property languageId found for type Project

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, java-8, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have two Entity class as shown below. Using JPARepository how can I findProjectByProjectIdAndLanguageId.

```
@Entity
public class ProjectDetails {

    @Id
    private int projectId;
    private String projectDescription;
    private int languageId;


}


@Entity
public class Project {

    @Id
    private int projectId;
    private String projectName;
    private LocalDate projectStartDate;
    private LocalDate projectEndDate;
    private String projectStatus;

    @OneToOne
    private ProjectDetails projectDetails;


}


@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Integer> {

    public List<Project> findProjectByProjectIdAndLanguageId(int projectId , int languageId);

}
```

I am getting below error when I start my spring boot application.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property languageId found for type Project!
```

Comment: The error clearly tells you what is wrong. Your `Project` entity doesn't have a `languageId` field.

Comment: Would like to know how I can solve it. Is there any way I can achieve what I really want?. These two are existing table and hence I cannot change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter on properties not on the aggregate root you'll have to provide the full path.
The following should work.

```
public List<Project> findProjectByProjectIdAndProjectDetailsLanguageId(int projectId , int languageId);
```

Comment: Thanks @Jens. I think this should solve my purpose. I am getting another error now "oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long".  Already added "spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl" in my spring boot configuration file.

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments. Just make a new proper question instead.

Comment: added a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61010482/oracle-jdbc-oracledatabaseexception-ora-00972-identifier-is-too-long/61010692#61010692