# oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, java-8, spring-data-jpa

Here is my Entity class

```
@Entity
public class ProjectDetails {

    @Id
    private int projectId;
    private String projectDescription;
    private int languageId;


}


@Entity
public class Project {

    @Id
    private int projectId;
    private String projectName;
    private LocalDate projectStartDate;
    private LocalDate projectEndDate;
    private String projectStatus;

    @OneToOne
    private ProjectDetails projectDetails;


}
```

I have a JPA method like this

```
List<Projects> findProjectsByProjectsIdAndProjectDetailsLanguageId(int projectId, int languageId)
```

While executing I am getting below error.

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long
```

Already added Physical-statergy naming configuration

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

I read about implicit-strategy but not sure about it. Any idea how to solve the issue?

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace from which one might tell which identifier the error is referring to?

Comment: @JensSchauder This is bit long "project0_.projectdetails_projectDescription".

Comment: It seems bizarre, why would it even need such an identifier? I can't see why the mapping you posted would warrant one like that. Could you please post the entire generated query?

Comment: @crizzis I am really sorry , due to security reason cannot post query here . The class is also a representation not an actual class I posted. But what if I get this error ? any cases even if you come across such issue what will be the solution.

Comment: Well, it's difficult to theorize without seeing the query. However, you can try switching to JPQL (using `@Query`) or Criteria API with `JpaSpecificationExecutor`. You'll then be able to override aliases for most joins using explicit aliasing in the query or `join.alias("")` with Criteria API, preventing them from becoming too long. Cannot guarantee this will work, though

Comment: And of course, if all else fails, just use a native query for full control

Comment: I just noticed `projectdetails_projectDescription` seems to be a column name, why not name it explicitly using a shorter name with `@JoinColumn(name = "...")`?

Comment: @crizzis JoinCloumn uses to map Foreignkey rt? Above example I can give like   OneToOne   JoinColumn(name = "projectId")
    private ProjectDetails projectDetails; (Removed at the rate as it was not allowing multiple times"

Comment: I tried Named Query but no success. Same error. I think altering table is the only way or go with Native query. Native query yet to try though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [2.8.1 Database Object Naming Rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA) taken from the Oracle DB **12.2** [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/):

> 1. The maximum length of identifier names depends on the value of the COMPATIBLE initialization parameter.
>
>    - If COMPATIBLE is set to a value of 12.2 or higher, then names must be from 1 to 128 bytes long with these exceptions:
>
>      - Names of databases are limited to 8 bytes.
>      - Names of disk groups, pluggable databases (PDBs), rollback segments, tablespaces, and tablespace sets are limited to 30 bytes.

For this version, the identifier is simply too long. The only way to go is to either use a shorter name or downgrade `COMPATIBLE` to a lower version.

Comment: Thanks Nikolas for the answer. Issue is not with the Oracle, Issue is with the ORAM tool which automatically creates the query. There is something called Naming Stratergy , it is implemented in my application and still not working. So your answer is not relevant for me.

Comment: Shouldn't COMPATIBLE be set to a higher version if at all possible? After all the limit in older versions was 30 characters (or bytes).

Comment: Uhm, I don't know. I try to search for something that might help you.